# Toggling permissions for AAD

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory

For the sake of clarity, I'd like to grant **all permissions** for this demo app.

In the example below, it looks like three items below **require the user to be an administrator** to access those items. Is that correct?

[image]

Also, if I wanted the user to access those items **without being an administrator**, how would I change that?

I would assume I could hit the *checkbox next to those items -> save -> grant permissions* but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For " In the example below, it looks like three items below **require the user to be an administrator** to access those items. Is that correct?", this is not correct. The "**No**" means not require the user to be an administrator and "**Yes**" means require the administrator.

And for you want the user to access all items, as I know, this cannot without being an administrator in the portal, so your operation doesn't work even though you already grant all permissions.